# Identify the same object from two image with changing back ground

Tags: image, similarity, identification

when we take a video from moving vehicle backward, we will see vehicles behind you moving slowly, while the background(trees, houses, road markers) moving quite fast. Given two successive images from the video, the car behind you will not change much, but the background change a lot. I would like to consult how to automatically identify this car from the two images. They share similar position, size and all other features.

The equivalent question is how to identify the background which changes a lot.

I do know there are a bunch of algorithms to identify vehicles and have tried some of them. But is it possible to use similarity of the same vehicle in successive images to identify the vehicle?

I am using a monocular camera and updating frequency is 2Hz.

Six successive images are uploaded as a reference.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of similarity, the classical way is to use histogram. Divide your graphs into small grid and computer RGB histogram for each grid. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, however, is there a more precise way to identify the position of vehicles. You could see clearly from the pictures I just uploaded there are minor changes for the vehicle behind.